# UIReferenceLibraryViewController iOS5

Tags: ios5

Is there a way to get the meaning of "terms" in "dictionary" by extracting the NSString * from the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` object?

Can we get meanings in strings to use wherever we want or are we bound to use the specifically designed yellow sand color view that is initialized by the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract meanings by this... However, extracting and modifying data from UIReferenceLibraryViewController will probably violate the dictionary publisher's copyright.

```
@interface UIWebView (Extension)
@end

@implementation UIWebView (Extension)
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
    NSLog(@"string %@",string);

    NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self loadData:data MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseURL];
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll not violate it.

Comment: Dear Cliff, there's one issue I'm still wondering. I can use the dictionary as is in a separate view controller right?

I'm wondering what if I make use of the origin of word information and shorten it a little bit and use it in another view of mine (a table view cell)? In this case, I'm reading the origin from the dictionary one by one and use the information but in a brief sentence. Obviously the origin of word information is everywhere on the internet, too. Would this violate the copyright?